# VBox shared folders not mounted under Ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, shared-folders

i am using a fresh installation of windows 10 + virtual box 6 + ubuntu 18 (in the vm)

i set up a shared folder in the virtual box ui after installing the guest additions, but the folder does not appear under /media/

what black magic do i need to perform to get this to work?

i already tried various things i found online (mounting, adding my user to some vboxsf group etc), but nothing had any effect.

i was using ubuntu 16 before, where adding a shared folder simply worked and added a new entry under /media
can someone point me at a todo list for absolute dummies that "just works"?

Comment: Sorry, I had to delete my answer. I was mistaken.

Comment: I no longer use the shared folder method, as I have had trouble with it.  Ubuntu does, however, support SAMBA and that is the normal manner of sharing winders directories over networks.  So, you could share the folder, start ubuntu and connect to the SAMBA share...

Comment: Hi @user1471827 I am also facing same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: i use resilio sync. it doubles the space requirement but works reliably